# Java. Умножение матриц произвольных размеров с помощью фиксированного числа поток

Tags: java, многопоточность, матрицы

я новичок в многопоточных вычислениях; Мне нужно умножить две матрицы с использованием потоков. Я хочу использовать ленточный алгоритм с использованием горизонтальных полос (т.е. строки первой исходной матрицы умножаем на столбцы второй исходной (т.е. на строки её транспонированной). Главные вопросы: как мне оформить циклический обмен строками транспонированной матрицы? И как мне из потоков вернуть tempRes для записи в Res. Заранее спасибо за помощь. Вот мой код:

Класс Main:

```
import static java.lang.Math.round;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final int n = 1;
    final int m = 2;
    final int k = 3;
    double[] arr_1 = new double[n * m];
    double[] arr_2 = new double[m * k];
    double[] res = new double[n * k];

    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++) {
        arr_1[i] = round(Math.random() * 50 + 100);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m * k; i++) {
        arr_2[i] = round(Math.random() * 40 + 20);
    }

    System.out.println("Show Matrix_1: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr_1[i * m + j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();


    System.out.println("Show Matrix_2: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr_2[i * k + j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();

    double[] new_arr_2 = new double[k * m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            new_arr_2[j * m + i] = arr_2[i * k + j];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Show New_Matrix_2: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            System.out.print(new_arr_2[i * m + j] + "  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
```

/* тут я равномерно распределяю строки массивов, т.к не факт, что они будут кратны количеству потоков */

```
    int kolvo_nerasprstrok_arr_1 = n;
    int kolvo_nerasprstrok_new_arr_2 = k;

    int kolvoThread = 3;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[kolvoThread];
    int []kolvoStrokThr_arr_1 = new int [kolvoThread];
    int []kolvoStrokThr_new_arr_2 = new int [kolvoThread];

    double timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = kolvoThread - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        kolvoStrokThr_arr_1[i] =  kolvo_nerasprstrok_arr_1 / (i + 1);
        kolvoStrokThr_new_arr_2[i] = kolvo_nerasprstrok_new_arr_2 / (i + 1);
        kolvo_nerasprstrok_arr_1 -= kolvoStrokThr_arr_1[i];
        kolvo_nerasprstrok_new_arr_2 -= kolvoStrokThr_new_arr_2[i];
    }
```

/* т.к. мы циклично пересылаем строки транспонированной матрицы, то нужно установить фиксированную одинаковую размерность для потоков. Иначе, допустим, я не знаю, как реализовать цикличный обмен, например, двух и трёх строк */

```
    int max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2 = 0;

    for (int i = kolvoThread - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (kolvoStrokThr_new_arr_2[i] >  max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2)
        {
            max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2 = kolvoStrokThr_new_arr_2[i];
        }
    }
```

/*делаю массивы с элементами для потоков, передаю их и запускаю сами потоки */

```
    int kolvo_raspred_elems_arr_1 = 0;
    int kolvo_raspred_elems_new_arr_2 = 0;
    for (int i = kolvoThread - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        double[] elems_1 = new double[kolvoStrokThr_arr_1[i] * m];
        double[] elems_2 = new double[max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2 * m];
        double[] tempRes = new double[kolvoStrokThr_arr_1[i] * max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2];
        int t = 0;
        for (int j = kolvo_raspred_elems_arr_1; j < kolvo_raspred_elems_arr_1 + kolvoStrokThr_arr_1[i] * m ; j++) {
            elems_1[t] = arr_1[j];
            t++;
        }
        t = 0;
        for (int j = kolvo_raspred_elems_new_arr_2; j < kolvo_raspred_elems_new_arr_2 + kolvoStrokThr_new_arr_2[i] * m; j++) {
            elems_2[t] = new_arr_2[j];
            t++;
        }

        System.out.println();
        kolvo_raspred_elems_arr_1 += kolvoStrokThr_arr_1[i] * m;
        kolvo_raspred_elems_new_arr_2 += kolvoStrokThr_new_arr_2[i] * m;
        threads[i] = new Thread(new Mult(kolvoStrokThr_arr_1[i],  max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2, elems_1, elems_2, tempRes, m), "Thread-" + i);
        threads[i].start();


    }
(*тут ещё немного кода дописать *)
```

Класс Mult:

```
public class Mult extends Thread{
private final int  m, kolvoStrokThr_arr_1,max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2;
private final  double []elems_1, elems_2, tempRes;

public Mult(int kolvoStrokThr_arr_1, int max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2 ,double[]elems_1, double[] elems_2, double[]tempRes,  int m)
{
    this.kolvoStrokThr_arr_1 = kolvoStrokThr_arr_1;
    this.max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2 = max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2;
    this.elems_1 = elems_1;
    this.elems_2 = elems_2;
    this.tempRes = tempRes;
    this.m = m;
}

@Override
public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (int i = 0; i < kolvoStrokThr_arr_1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < max_strok_Thr_new_arr_2; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
                    tempRes[i * m + j] += elems_1[i * m + k] * elems_2[j * m + k];
                    System.out.println(elems_1[i * m + k]);
                    System.out.println(elems_2[j * m + k]);
                    System.out.println(tempRes[i * m + j]);
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно? У вас есть 2 исходные матрицы и одна результирующая. Минимальная задача у вас, это рассчитать конкретный элемент (i,j) результирующей матрицы. Всё, что для этого нужно - это 3 матрицы, их размерность и индекс элемента для расчета. Всё. Напишите функцию, которая принимает эти параметры, и запускайте эту функцию с разными (i,j) многопоточно.

Comment: Можете запустить по потоку на столбец, по потоку на строку или по потоку на ячейку. Если вам надо фиксированное количество потоков, то есть же всякие экзекуторы в джаве. Если упороться хочется, ищите паттерн producer-consumer.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите предложить общий доступ к массивам с указателями на начало/конец для каждого потока без разделения их на "подмассивы"? Изначально я так сделал, но преподаватель сказал, что нужно работать как с разделённой памятью(.
А насчёт потока на каждую строку/cтолбец - допустим, с матрицей 1000 на 1000 получится 1000 потоков, если я правильно понял. Разве это логично для каждой строки/столбца создавать один поток, это не слишком "прожорливо"?..

Comment: Это учебное задание, потому я не знаю что для него логично, а что нет. Обрабатывать матрицу 1000х1000 мгогопоточностью в принципе излишне, один поток это сделать может возможно даже быстрее, чем несколько потоков. Но вообще конечно стартовать 1000 потоков смысла не имеет, это больше к тормозам приведет.